# Build failure with an exception flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

`
../../../../../AppData/Local/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-3.0.0/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:46:19: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use
^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           20.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1`

i cloned a swiggy ui to learn and started to build the apk from [github repo](https://github.com/vinothvino42/SwiggyUI) and tried to build locally, just a beginner in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Read the article:

https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/270/error-member-not-found-packageroot-flutter/

It might help you. The article provided four possible solutions. Try all the solutions & try your luck. If it does not work, then give me your flutter doctor summary.